# multi login in different user using php and mysql

Tags: php

im creating a login page which is there are different multi user can login such as student, manager and stuff..
when im trying to run my code, it shows empty page, can anyone help with my code?
im new in php and mysqli code
below shows the image of my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD5Av.png)

```
<?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($rows==1)
        {
            if($rows ['level'] == "student")
            {
                header("localtion: student.php");
            }
            elseif($rows ['level'] == "manager")
            {
                header("location: manager.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "wrong Username or Password";
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css2/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>

</div>
<?php } ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart of the problem which you have there is another one.. this is now how `mysqli_*` is supposed to be used..

Comment: Side note, look into `password_hash()`/`password_verify()`, `md5()` is not sufficient for password verifying. Also, you should be putting `exit;` after your redirects.

Comment: @S.I. is probably referring to using parameterized queries. [The answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) explains about them.

Comment: @Terminus, yes.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra 
`<?php } ?>` (3rd line from last).

It should be just before `?>
<!DOCTYPE html>`

i.e it should be like: 
`} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: if i remove the <?php } ?> in 3rd last line it shows error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\DrivingSchool\login.php on line 56"

Comment: Did you put the `}' before your closing `?>` tag?

Comment: yes, i did put it, something wrong with my query? because if i delete my process.. the form display it well

Comment: write echo $query & comment the execution of query,So that you will able find what is the query shows.

Comment: why down vote this? must write the cause